# I have Blockchain.info wallet which i can't find

Tags: blockchain-wallet-app

I opened up an account with a site called Blockchain.info got a username and password, got a Bitcoin wallet address. I then bought some bitcoins sent them to that address, the bitcoins left but now i cannot access any blockchain.info site that gives me access to my account. Does anyone know what is going on with Blockchain.info?

Comment: "now i cannot access any block chain site that gives me access to my account": This is extremely vague.  What exactly did you do, and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

1) Blockchain.info was down for a few moments in recent days - please re-check it's availability.

2) Blockchain.info sends an email confirmation with your wallet's "Identifier". This is your login/username. Try searching your email for "blockchain" and see if you have that email. 
Subject: Welcome To My Wallet
Body:

> This email contains important information about your new bitcoin
>   wallet. Be sure to keep this safe and stored separately from your
>   password.
>
> Login Link:
>   https://blockchain.info/wallet/9c......
>
> Notifications: Notifications Are Disabled Confirmation Code: D9028
>
> Verification Link: 
>   https://blockchain.info/wallet/verify-email?data=xxxxxxxxxx

Clicking the first link to your wallet will pre-fill your identifier (login), and just need the password you set when you started. That will get you into your account.